# python: how to delete registry key (and subkeys) from HKLM (getting error 5)

Tags: python, registry, winreg

I'm trying to delete certain registry keys, via python script.
i have no problems reading and deleting keys from the "HKEY_CURRENT_USER", but trying to do the same from the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", gives me the dreaded **WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied**.
i'm running the script via the IDLE IDE, with admin privileges.
here's the code:

```
from _winreg import *    
ConnectRegistry(None,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,r'software\wow6432node\App',0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
DeleteKey(OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,r'software\wow6432node'),'App')
```

Comment: Can you delete that key using `regedit` from the same user?

Comment: @cdarke - yes. when i open `regedit` it runs as admin (the UAC dialog is shown). i can navigate to the desired key and delete it, along with it's subkeys.
maybe the problem with the script is that it fails because 'software\wow6432node\App' contains additional subkeys.

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove all subkeys before you can delete the key.

```
def deleteSubkey(key0, key1, key2=""):
    import _winreg
    if key2=="":
        currentkey = key1
    else:
        currentkey = key1+ "\\" +key2

    open_key = _winreg.OpenKey(key0, currentkey ,0,_winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
    infokey = _winreg.QueryInfoKey(open_key)
    for x in range(0, infokey[0]):
        #NOTE:: This code is to delete the key and all subkeys.
        #  If you just want to walk through them, then 
        #  you should pass x to EnumKey. subkey = _winreg.EnumKey(open_key, x)
        #  Deleting the subkey will change the SubKey count used by EnumKey. 
        #  We must always pass 0 to EnumKey so we 
        #  always get back the new first SubKey.
        subkey = _winreg.EnumKey(open_key, 0)
        try:
            _winreg.DeleteKey(open_key, subkey)
            print "Removed %s\\%s " % ( currentkey, subkey)
        except:
            deleteSubkey( key0, currentkey, subkey )
            # no extra delete here since each call 
            #to deleteSubkey will try to delete itself when its empty.

    _winreg.DeleteKey(open_key,"")
    open_key.Close()
    print "Removed %s" % (currentkey)
    return
```

Here is an how you run it:

```
deleteSubkey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "software\\wow6432node", "App")
deleteSubkey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "software\\wow6432node\\App")
```

Comment: Hi this recursion does not end, i got "maximum recursion depth exceeded " exception, when trying to delete winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\'+str(ver)+'\\Excel\\Resiliency'

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution. I like to use `with` statements in order to not have to close the key manually. First I check for sub keys and delete them before I delete the key itself. `EnumKey` raises an OSError if no sub key exists. I use this to break out of the loop.

```python
from winreg import *

def delete_key(key: Union[HKEYType, int], sub_key_name: str):
    with OpenKey(key, sub_key_name) as sub_key:
        while True:
            try:
                sub_sub_key_name = EnumKey(sub_key, 0)
                delete_key(sub_key, sub_sub_key_name)
            except OSError:
                break

    DeleteKey(key, sub_key_name)
```

Comment: **This is 100x more beautiful than all the other answers. Thank you!** I even love how you loop until `OSError` which is exactly what `EnumKey` docs suggest: "It is typically called repeatedly until an OSError exception is raised, indicating no more values are available."

Answer (score 3):

Just my two cents on the topic, but I recurse to the lowest subkey and delete on unravel:

```
def delete_sub_key(root, sub):
    
    try:
        open_key = winreg.OpenKey(root, sub, 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
        num, _, _ = winreg.QueryInfoKey(open_key)
        for i in range(num):
            child = winreg.EnumKey(open_key, 0)
            delete_sub_key(open_key, child)
        try:
           winreg.DeleteKey(open_key, '')
        except Exception:
           # log deletion failure
        finally:
           winreg.CloseKey(open_key)
    except Exception:
        # log opening/closure failure
```

The difference between the other posts is that I do not try to delete if `num` is >0 because it will fail implicitly (as stated in the docs). So I don't waste time to try if there are subkeys.

Comment: +1 Short and concise. Could still use a `with winreg.OpenKey(..) as open_key:` context to save yourself the `finally:` block!

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT]
I have created a pip package that handles registry keys.
Install with: `pip install windows_tools.registry`

Usage:

```
from windows_tools.registry import delete_sub_key, KEY_WOW64_32KEY, KEY_WOW64_64KEY

keys = ['SOFTWARE\MyInstalledApp', 'SOFTWARE\SomeKey\SomeOtherKey']
for key in keys:
    delete_sub_key(key, arch=KEY_WOW64_32KEY | KEY_WOW64_64KEY)
```

[/EDIT]

Unburying this old question, here's an updated version of ChrisHiebert's recursive function that:

- Handles Python 3 (tested with Python 3.7.1)
- Handles multiple registry architectures (eg Wow64 for Python 32 on Windows 64)
- Is PEP-8 compliant

The following example shows function usage to delete two keys in all registry architectures (standard and redirected WOW6432Node) by using architecture key masks.
Hopefully this will help someone:

```
    import winreg


    def delete_sub_key(key0, current_key, arch_key=0):

        open_key = winreg.OpenKey(key0, current_key, 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS | arch_key)
        info_key = winreg.QueryInfoKey(open_key)
        for x in range(0, info_key[0]):
            # NOTE:: This code is to delete the key and all sub_keys.
            # If you just want to walk through them, then
            # you should pass x to EnumKey. sub_key = winreg.EnumKey(open_key, x)
            # Deleting the sub_key will change the sub_key count used by EnumKey.
            # We must always pass 0 to EnumKey so we
            # always get back the new first sub_key.
            sub_key = winreg.EnumKey(open_key, 0)
            try:
                winreg.DeleteKey(open_key, sub_key)
                print("Removed %s\\%s " % (current_key, sub_key))
            except OSError:
                delete_sub_key(key0, "\\".join([current_key,sub_key]), arch_key)
                # No extra delete here since each call
                # to delete_sub_key will try to delete itself when its empty.

        winreg.DeleteKey(open_key, "")
        open_key.Close()
        print("Removed %s" % current_key)
        return


    # Allows to specify if operating in redirected 32 bit mode or 64 bit, set arch_keys to 0 to disable
    arch_keys = [winreg.KEY_WOW64_32KEY, winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY]
    
    # Base key
    root = winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
    
    # List of keys to delete
    keys = ['SOFTWARE\MyInstalledApp', 'SOFTWARE\SomeKey\SomeOtherKey']

    for key in keys:
        for arch_key in arch_keys:
            try:
                delete_sub_key(root, key, arch_key)
            except OSError as e:
                print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!
turns out the registry key wasn't empty and contained multiple subkeys.
i had to enumerate and delete the subkeys first, and only then i was able to delete the main key from HKLM.
(also added "try...except", so it wouldn't break the whole code, it case there were problems).