# How do I delete regedit keys in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, registry, regedit

I was just wondering how would I delete multiple regedit keys using a python script? or how I'd do it in a different language then call that class inside of my python script. (But I'd  prefer to just do it in python)

Comment: Your answer should be here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205784/python-how-to-delete-registry-key-and-subkeys-from-hklm-getting-error-5

Comment: How do I delete the sub keys? The problem was never solved in there until he manually deleted the subkeys and I need the script to automate that process but I don't know how.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.